# Want my girlfriend to visit me for 1-2 weeks

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas, dominican-republic, dominican-citizens

I am an American citizen and my girlfriend is Dominican. I would really like her to spend 1-2 weeks with me in the U.S. (I really want her to get a taste). As of now she doesn't have any kind of visa and has been rather resistant towards getting a non-immigrant visa (she says it's because she wants to migrate some day and is afraid it might ruin her chances. But she also says she just doesn't know when, or if it'll even happen for sure).

Is it possible for me, from the U.S., to help her find a way to be able to spend at least 7 days here (like a sort of visa waiver program, or something)? I am hoping that if she gets a taste, then she'll be able to better make a decision on when and if she will migrate (I know about the fiancee visa, but I find her too unsure to put that on the table)...

Comment: Ah, you are not allowed an ESTA from DR?

Comment: @JoeBlow Not sure this is a question.  ESTA is only for VWP countries.  Dominican Republic isn't one of them.

Comment: If she doesn't want to follow the obvious route of getting a B2 visitor visa, then I don't think she has any other options. The entire purpose of the non-immigrant visitor visa is to allow short-term visits. I don't think there are any "I want to visit for a short time, I need a visa but don't want to get one" visa.

Comment: That's too bad that DR is not in the ESTA-VWProgramme.  Bummer!

Comment: Thanks for all the information! I did some reasearch and her only two choices seem to be the K-1 or the B-2... I am going to try to convince her to get a B-2. I do have a question, though, and this is unrelated to my case, but if someone were to get a K-1 visa with person X, and they decided to not marry this person X. If they went back to their country, would it hurt their chances to get another K-1 visa with person another Y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. There are no visa waiver programs for girlfriends or anything like that. There is a special visa (K-1) for girlfriends who are coming to marry an US citizen, but it is still a visa, not a visa waiver.

She has some other options depending on her age, skill, occupation and other qualities (work-and-travel, study, sport/religion/whatever), but she would still need a visa.

Having a non-immigrant visa will NOT hurt her chances to immigrate to US at all. When she applies for one, she states it is not her intent to immigrate to the USA **right now**. She never states, and it is never assumed, that she would never have such intent in future.

If this helps, I've myself had a US non-immigrant visa before immigrating to the US. So did my parents, who got the US non-immigrant visas to visit me, and then changed their status when I applied for a green card for them.